# Running a set returning function on all the rows in a postgres table and getting all the results back

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.1

I have a PostgreSQL 9.1 database with a svn version of PostGIS 2.0. I have a set returning function from postgis (ST_DumpAsPolygon), which takes one row and returns many rows. I have a table of data and want to run the set returning function on each row of the input and return all the rows. However `SELECT ST_DumpAsPolygon(rast) FROM mytable` seems to return the values from only one row. Is there some way to get the set returning function to run on every row in the table, and collect all the results together, and return all those results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think I made a mistake. An error in a previous step of a process led me to think there were things in there that weren't in the table, and hence I thought that the set returning function wasn't doing things.

This should probably be closed.